# Unicast video streaming on FreeBSD

Tags: video

I need to broadcast one live video stream from Windows machine (captured by TV tuner) to many viewers in the Internet.
Because bandwidth is limited on this machine it should be forwarded to FreeBSD machine in datacenter and than forwarded to final viewers. I expect near 100-200 viewers watching simultaneously.

So, the question is, what software recommended on windows site, and on FreeBSD machine?
What pros and cons of different software?

---

One of the options is VLC - it can send captured stream out of windows machine. On FreeBSD server side VLC can broadcast this stream to viewers in unicast.
Any other options? especially for FreeBSD server site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at Darwin Streaming Server, it will run on FreeBSD and other operating systems.

For live brodcast with a TV tuner, you would use QuickTime Broadcaster for that.

You can also use VLC to brodcast throug the Darwin streaming server, see http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_a_live_video_feed_to_Darwin_Streaming_Server_for_Mobile_Phones

Answer (score 0):

First off how will forwarding to another host save bandwith, you will need to get all the traffic to the box in the datacenter anyway?

Since it's a TV tuner I assume you want to stream a single source to multiple clients. VLC should be able to do that.

Comment: I need to broadcast only 1 video stream to multiple viewers. Only 1 video stream should go from windows machine to freebsd server. From server video should be translated in unicast.